# Shuffling two numpy arrays for a NN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network

I have two numpy arrays for input data X and output data y.

```
X = np.array(([2, 3],                    # sample 1 x
              [16, 4]), dtype=float)     # sample 2 x
y = np.array(([1, 0],                    # sample 1 y
              [0, 1]), dtype=float)      # sample 2 y
```

I am wanting to use mini batches in order to train a NN, how can I shuffle both arrays knowing that the corresponding output is still aligned?

Comment: check out sklearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an array of indexes with same shape as the respective arrays and each time shuffle the index array. In that case you can use the shuffled indexes to realign both arrays in a same way.

```
In [122]: indices = np.indices((2, 2))

In [125]: np.random.shuffle(indices)

In [126]: indices
Out[126]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])

In [127]: x[indices[0], indices[1]]
Out[127]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [16.,  4.]])

In [128]: y[indices[0], indices[1]]
Out[128]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Seems great, but would this still work if my arrays of x and y were not the same shape?

Comment: @Wizard No, but in that case it depends on how you define the notion of being aligned.

Comment: Just in relation to rows

Comment: @Wizard There might be a similar way for that but it's better to show this with an example or you can ask another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with sklearn:

```
X, null, y, null = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0, random_state=42)
```

It keep aligned X and y