# Randomly shuffle items in each row of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like the following:

```
Xtrain = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6],
                   [1, 7, 3]])
```

I want to shuffle the items of each row separately, but do not want the shuffle to be the same for each row (as in several examples just shuffle column order).

For example, I want an output like the following:

```
output = np.array([[3, 2, 1],
                   [4, 6, 5],
                   [7, 3, 1]])
```

How can I randomly shuffle each of the rows randomly in an efficient way? My actual np array is over 100000 rows and 1000 columns.

Comment: @Kasramvd According to np documentation, Multi-dimensional arrays are only shuffled along the first axis:

`>>>
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
>>> np.random.shuffle(arr)
>>> arr
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [0, 1, 2]])`

Comment: Yes `suffle()` doesn't accept axis argument. Here is a similar question tho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415972/shuffling-two-numpy-arrays-for-a-nn/50416056#50416056

Comment: @Kasramvd If I understand it, this question wants to shuffle row order, not the actual values in the rows.

Answer (score 7):

Since you want to only shuffle the columns you can just perform the [*shuffling*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) on transposed of your matrix:

```
In [86]: np.random.shuffle(Xtrain.T)

In [87]: Xtrain
Out[87]: 
array([[2, 3, 1],
       [5, 6, 4],
       [7, 3, 1]])
```

Note that [random.suffle()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) on a 2D array shuffles the rows not items in each rows. i.e. changes the position of the rows. Therefor if your change the position of the transposed matrix rows you're actually shuffling the columns of your original array.

If you still want a completely independent shuffle you can create random indexes for each row and then create the final array with a simple indexing:

```
In [172]: def crazyshuffle(arr):
     ...:     x, y = arr.shape
     ...:     rows = np.indices((x,y))[0]
     ...:     cols = [np.random.permutation(y) for _ in range(x)]
     ...:     return arr[rows, cols]
     ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [173]: crazyshuffle(Xtrain)
Out[173]: 
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [7, 3, 1]])

In [174]: crazyshuffle(Xtrain)
Out[174]: 
array([[2, 3, 1],
       [4, 6, 5],
       [1, 3, 7]])
```

Answer (score 3):

From: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5173

```
def disarrange(a, axis=-1):
    """
    Shuffle `a` in-place along the given axis.

    Apply numpy.random.shuffle to the given axis of `a`.
    Each one-dimensional slice is shuffled independently.
    """
    b = a.swapaxes(axis, -1)
    # Shuffle `b` in-place along the last axis.  `b` is a view of `a`,
    # so `a` is shuffled in place, too.
    shp = b.shape[:-1]
    for ndx in np.ndindex(shp):
        np.random.shuffle(b[ndx])
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is not efficient by any means, but I had fun thinking about it, so wrote it down. Basically, you ravel the array, and create an array of row labels, and an array of indices. You shuffle the index array, and index the original and row label arrays with that. Then you apply a **stable** argsort to the row labels to gather the data into rows. Apply that index and reshape and viola, data shuffled independently by rows:

```
import numpy as np

r, c = 3, 4  # x.shape

x = np.arange(12) + 1  # Already raveled 
inds = np.arange(x.size)
rows = np.repeat(np.arange(r).reshape(-1, 1), c, axis=1).ravel()

np.random.shuffle(inds)
x = x[inds]
rows = rows[inds]

inds = np.argsort(rows, kind='mergesort')
x = x[inds].reshape(r, c)
```

Here is an [IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/OL8jnB)

Answer (score 2):

We can create a random 2-dimensional matrix, sort it by each row, and then use the index matrix given by `argsort` to reorder the target matrix.

```
target = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 5))
# [[7 4 0 2 5]
# [5 6 4 8 7]
# [6 4 7 9 5]
# [8 6 6 2 8]
# [8 1 6 7 3]]

shuffle_helper = np.argsort(np.random.rand(5,5), axis=1)
# [[0 4 3 2 1]
# [4 2 1 3 0]
# [1 2 3 4 0]
# [1 2 4 3 0]
# [1 2 3 0 4]]

target[np.arange(shuffle_helper.shape[0])[:, None], shuffle_helper]
# array([[7, 5, 2, 0, 4],
#       [7, 4, 6, 8, 5],
#       [4, 7, 9, 5, 6],
#       [6, 6, 8, 2, 8],
#       [1, 6, 7, 8, 3]])
```

**Explanation**

- We use `np.random.rand` and `argsort` to mimic the effect from shuffling.
- `random.rand` gives randomness.
- Then, we use `argsort` with `axis=1` to help rank each row. This creates the index that can be used for reordering.

Comment: How would that be better than sorting the rows of the original directly?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorting the original directly would lead to one same result and leave no randomness.

Comment: I just got it. You're using the fact that `argsort` has an axis argument to compensate for `shuffle`'s lack. Clever

Comment: @MadPhysicist exactly! Thanks for taking time to understand this thought.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have array `a` with shape 100000 x 1000.

```
b = np.random.choice(100000 * 1000, (100000, 1000), replace=False)
ind = np.argsort(b, axis=1)
a_shuffled = a[np.arange(100000)[:,np.newaxis], ind]
```

I don't know if this is faster than loop, because it needs sorting, but with this solution maybe you will invent something better, for example with `np.argpartition` instead of `np.argsort`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Pandas`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(X_train)
_ = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.permutation(x), axis=1, raw=True)
df.values
```

Change the keyword to `axis=0` if you want to shuffle columns.